# Using result of one helper function in another helper function within Handlebars

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am checking if there is anyway that I can use the result of one helper function in another helper function and how can I use it, for example, I am looping through as below

```
{{#each v.NOVNumber as |vv iindex|}}
```

And then if I am getting another element as below, using the same index:

```
{{get v.NOVNoticeTypeName iindex}}
```

Can I use this element that we have got in a statement like below, to check if that is first or last element etc?

```
{{#if (isFirst v.NOVNumber vv)}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You you can use helpers together to create more powerful functions. [Ember Composable Helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers) provides both a good pattern for using helpers together as well as the specific [has-next](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#has-next) and [has-previous](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#has-previous) helpers that you need to know if an element is first of last.

An example using `has-next`

```
{{#if (has-next page pages)}}
  <button>Next</button>
{{/if}}
```